# Multithreaded sorting and fixing of a wordlist

Tags: sorting, utf-8, sed, parallel-processing, uniq

I am trying to sort my wordlist. I want to remove: all white space, all duplicates except one of each word, all non UTF-8 characters. I also want to sort the list by smallest first.

I/O is less of an issue because I am running a SSD, thus I want to multi-thread this script. The script bellow seems to be removing a lot more than it should.

```
#!/bin/bash
page=`grep '' -R "wordlist.txt"  | iconv -f utf8 -t utf8 -c | 
parallel --pipe  "sed -e 's/[[:space:]]/\n/g' | grep -v '^$'" |
parallel --pipe  sed '/[^a-zA-Z1-9]/d' | parallel --pipe  sort -u | parallel --pipe  uniq`

echo "$page" > wordlistfixed.txt
```

The script is removing too much.
I have 5 entries of the word "and" in the list, and all of them are removed. Leaving no entries of the word "and". I believe this is due to the use of `sort -u | uniq`. I've seen several scripts using this, but some research leads me to believe that `sort | uniq` = `sort -u` which then makes my use of `sort -u | uniq` pointless. I'm using parallel because previous scrips have been limited by CPU usage and not I/O.

The purpose of this wordlist is to do some password strength analasys.

Update:
I've made some more progress on this script.

```
cat in.txt | parallel --pipe sed -e 's/[[:space:]]/\n/g'|  grep -v '^$' |
parallel --pipe sed '/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/d' |  sort -u  > out.txt
```

This seems to do everything I want except remove unwanted characters.

Comment: Can you provide an example that demonstrates the script is removing too much?  What do you expect it to remove?  What is it actually removing?

Comment: Why do you need parallel? How many words are in wordlist.txt?  There are only 600,000 words in the OED. This question just brings up so many other issues. why `page=..`. Why `grep '' -R ..`. Others ... There is almost certainly a much simpler solution to what you are trying to achieve. Consider editing your question to include a small sample set of words, your required output from that sample, and your current output. Good luck.

Comment: sed doesn't work with UTF-8.

Comment: sed '/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/d' this will delete the lines that have non-alphanumeric characters not the characters, is that what you want? You may want: sed 's/[^a-Z0-9]//g'  this will rid you of all non-alphanumeric characters yet leave whatever else is on the line.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the shell runs all the programs in a pipeline in parallel anyway; you really don't need the `parallel` program. Since your final pipeline doesn't include the `iconv` transformation, it is not very surprising that the unwanted characters are not all removed properly. The final `sed` command deletes any line that contains a non-alphanumeric character, which is probably a bit dramatic.

```
iconv -f utf8 -t utf8 -c wordlist.txt |  # Remove invalid UTF-8 byte sequences
tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' |                 # Convert white space to newlines
sed '/^[:space:]*$/d' |                  # Delete blank lines (one at most)
sort -u > wordlistfixed.txt              # Sort the data eliminating duplicates
```

Superficially, that should be sufficient.  Note that this avoids the UUoC (Useless Use of `cat`) award, too.